# How can I determine why macOS reports that system data increased by over 50 Gb overnight?

Tags: macos, time-machine, disk-utility, partition

I recently had some trouble with System data growing large, up to 150 Gb, for unclear reasons on macOS  Monterey, macOS 12.0 Beta.

Yesterday I found out that it was due to time machine snapshots. I ran `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 1000000000`, which reduced system data to 30 Gb. This morning, however, I saw that system data had again increased to 85 Gb. The `tmutil` command doesn't seem to work now. I did disable automatic backups in the Time Machine preferences.

Here is the output of `diskutil list internal`, and some additional screen shots:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     132.2 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 925.4 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            31.0 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 31.0 GB    disk1s5s1
```

Also, I'm curious if the containers and volumes hierarchy shown on the left of the Disk Utility screenshot looks normal.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how to reclaim this space, or how to find out what it contains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really *need* to reclaim the space. Time Machine will clear it itself, as part of every 'real' backup task. There’s a check to pre clean and post destination as well as clean up the source.

To see these snapshots, open disk utility and select the view menu item named Show APFS Snapshots (command - shift - s)

[image: Disk Utility - Show APFS Snapshots]

From there you can see the private size of each snapshot and remove them if needed.

You cannot [as far as i'm aware] disable these internal backups. Disabling the main backup will not affect it, and *may* cause it to use even more space as it's waiting longer to be able to do a full backup.

If you delete it manually, it will simply refill again. If you need the space for something else, then Time Machine will just, in effect, move out of your way and use less & less - though by the time you are really fighting it for space, your drive is too full. You should always leave 10-15%. Right now, you have plenty of space, so there's no conflict.

Comment: Currently there is indeed no problem. I just hope it won't grow back to the 150 Gb it used to be, because then I was getting warnings that I was running out of space.

Comment: It should behave itself if you regularly back up to a 'real' Time Machine.

Comment: Aha, that might have been the issue, it was a while ago 